# False positive rate and false negative rate on testing the fairness of a number of coins

Tags: probability, statistics, combinations, hypothesis-testing

I faced a problem which can be described as follow:

There are 9 independent coins that we don't know if each is biased or no. One can toss them individually and use binomial test to test if it is biased.

Let's assume $\alpha$ for false positive rate and $\beta$ for false negative rate. In the first tossing round, one finds that there are 4 hypothesis tests are significant, and conclude 4 "biased" coins after tossing them for enough times respectively. Then one selects these 4 "biased" coins, and run the 2nd tossing round, now one gets 3 hypothesis tests are significant. Finally, one concludes that these 3 coins are biased.

So the question is, given the above scenario, what is the overall false positive rate and false negative rate?

My approach for calculating false positive rate is

$\binom 94$*$\alpha$<sup>4</sup> $\binom 43$*$\alpha$<sup>3</sup>

Similarly, for false negative rate is

$\binom 94$*$\alpha$<sup>9 - 4</sup> $\binom 43$*$\beta$<sup>4 - 3</sup>

I wonder if my approach is correct or not. Thanks for any comments!

Comment: If you do not actually know how many of the coins are biased (you just have some tests, a couple of which point in different directions), how do you expect to measure this?

Comment: @Henry I don't know. This was an interview question I was facing and I was not able to answer it. The approach I mentioned above is my guess

Comment: @Henry I have slightly rephrased my wording. The question aims to know what is the false positive and false negative given the multiple hypothesis testing in two rounds